# How does Python differentiate between the different data types?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is quite noobish to you, but I'm just starting out to learn Python after learning C++ & Java, and I am wondering how in the world I could just declare variables like `id = 0` and `name = 'John'` without any `int`'s or `string`'s in front! I figured out that perhaps it's because there are no `'`'s in a number, but how would Python figure that out in something like `def increase(first, second)` instead of something like `int increase(int first, int second)` in C++?!

Comment: Just a hint: don't name your variables stuff like "id", it'll override the built in function id(). In Python, functions are first-class objects, so they share the namespace with variables.

Comment: one thing i learnt from python::boost is that everything, i mean __everything__ in python is from type Object (python Object). Thats how it is possible that an int can be string or char or float or whatever, its all an object and is handled that way. str, int, etc are just derivatives of object and thus can be transformed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The literal objects you mention carry (pointers to;-) their own types with them of course, so when a name's bound to that object the problem of type doesn't arise -- the object always has a type, the name doesn't -- just delegates that to the object it's bound to.

There's no "figuring out" in `def increase(first, second):` -- name `increase` gets bound to a function object, names `first` and `second` are recorded as parameters-names and will get bound (quite possibly to objects of different types at various points) as `increase` gets called.

So say the body is `return first + second` -- a call to `increase('foo', 'bar')` will then happily return `'foobar'` (delegating the addition to the objects, which in this case are strings), and maybe later a call to `increase(23, 45)` will just as happily return `68` -- again by delegating the addition to the objects bound to those names at the point of call, which in this case are ints.  And if you call with incompatible types you'll get an exception as the delegated addition operation can't make sense of the situation -- no big deal!

Comment: Thanks to both you and everyone else who contributed! :)

Answer (score 7):

Python is *dynamically typed*: all variables can refer to an object of any type. `id` and `name` can be anything, but the actual objects are of types like `int` and `str`. `0` is a literal that is parsed to make an `int` object, and `'John'` a literal that makes a `str` object. Many object types do not have literals and are returned by a callable (like `frozenset`—there's no way to make a literal frozenset, you must call `frozenset`.)

Consequently, there is no such thing as declaration of variables, since you aren't defining anything about the variable. `id = 0` and `name = 'John'` are just assignment.

`increase` returns an `int` because that's what you return in it; nothing in Python forces it not to be any other object. `first` and `second` are only ints if you make them so.

Objects, to a certain extent, share a common interface. You can use the same operators and functions on them all, and if they support that particular operation, it works. It is a common, recommended technique to use different types that behave similarly interchangably; this is called *duck typing*. For example, if something takes a `file` object you can instead pass a `cStringIO.StringIO` object, which supports the same method as a file (like `read` and `write`) but is a completely different type. This is sort of like Java interfaces, but does not require any formal usage, you just define the appropriate methods.

Comment: Thanks! I would totally upvote you, but unfortunately my daily vote limit has been reached.

Answer (score 6):

Python uses the duck-typing method - if it walks, looks and quacks like a duck, then it's a duck. If you pass in a string, and try to do something numerical on it, then it will fail.

Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Typing and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to assigning literal values to variables, the type of the literal value can be inferred at the time of lexical analysis.  For example, anything matching the regular expression `(-)?[1-9][0-9]*` can be inferred to be an integer literal.  If you want to convert it to a float, there needs to be an explicit cast.  Similarly, a string literal is any sequence of characters enclosed in single or double quotes.

In a method call, the parameters are not type-checked.  You only need to pass in the correct number of them to be able to call the method.  So long as the body of the method does not cause any errors with respect to the arguments, you can call the same method with lots of different types of arguments.

Comment: (Of course, the actual lexical analysis rules for parsing are a tad more complicated than this.)

Comment: Also, to be pedantic, `(-)?[1-9][0-9]*` would be what a *decimal* integer literal looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, Unlike in C++ and Java, numbers and strings are both objects.  So this:

```
   id = 0
   name = 'John'
```

is equivalent to:

```
   id = int(0)
   name = str('John')
```

Since variables `id` and `name` are references that may address any Python object, they don't need to be declared with a particular type.

Comment: There are a few things misleading about this post. 

1) It is true that ints and strs are objects in Python and the C++ and Java have some primitive types as well as objects, but this is not why you do not have to declare variables in Python.

2) The equivalent code would be `id = int(0)` and `name = str('John')`; `Number` and `String` are not the names of anything in Python, and it doesn't really clear anything up to rephrase such things, considering this still requires creating `int` and `str` objects from literals.

3) "object pointers" is not a technical term in the context of Python AFAIK

Comment: Good points, Mike; edits made.  The point of replacing literals with constructors, though, is that it is less obvious to a beginner that literals return object references.

Comment: I hope it is effective in doing so, though it doesn't *really* get around the fact that those literals make objects (that are then passed to `int` and `str`).

Also, welcome to SO! =)