# How does python differentiate between signed and unsigned data type?

Tags: python, types

In Java or C++ we have a data type called `unsigned double` or `unsigned int` etc. How does python differentiate between them? I am asking this because in some cases we known that the numbers are not going to be negative so its better to use `unsigned`. The ranges are different for both type of data types.

I have already gone through a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445193/how-does-python-differentiate-between-the-different-data-types) but it addresses the general idea.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't.  There is no such distinction in the Python builtin types, because there are no unsigned numeric types.

Comment: Then isn;'t it a drawback since unsigned integer has a bigger range on the positive side.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: Of course. But speed isn't the primary reason for using Python in the first place.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: It depends on what you consider a drawback.  Python integers aren't just primitive floating-point types; they're Python objects.  So you can make a Python int (positive or negative) as big as you want.  The drawback, if any, is that this flexibility makes operations of the numbers slower, but the tradeoff is you can almost completely forget about the kinds of nitty-gritty details that you're asking about in your question.

Comment: Hmmm. This makes sense. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unsigned/signed distinction in python. However, if you absolutely must have unsigned integers you can always import types from the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module.